# How to sort the multiple arrays based on a single array in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c-2.0

I'm having a table view.The table view cells are filled with 5 different columns with 5 different array.If i sort the array in one column all other column should reorder based on the sorting.How can i do that one.

Comment: What do you mean by columns? Can you post the code/screenshot of what you are doing?

Comment: i want sort the multiple arrays based on the value in one array

Comment: What values are there in your array?

Comment: Can you give more detail in your question?

Comment: A comment as it doesn't actually answer the question put: the normal way to achieve this sort of thing would be to have each array entry contain the value for all five columns as a piece of compound data. Sort the one array, get the values for all five from there. You can use a custom class, an NSDictionary or even an NSValue wrapping a struct or C++ class if you're communicating with a non-Objective-C backend.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the NSMutableArray doc and the method you searching for is
`-(void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject`